# Find files older than X days excluding some other files

Tags: linux, find, solaris

i'm trying to write a shell script, for linux and solaris, that finds some specific files older than X days and then deletes them. the trick is that during this process there are a couple of files that must not be deleted.

for example from the following list of files i need to delete *.zip and keep *.log and *.something.*
1.zip
2.zip
3.log
prefix.something.suffix

finding the files and feeding them to rm was easy, but i'm having difficulties in excluding the files from the deletion list.

Comment: @Grove, I would create a script which I would feed the result of find, then in that script I would contain a list of files to be excluded. Very simple, something like, `if not in list; then rm -rf ${file} else ... fi`

Comment: the problem is that the files to be excluded are not the same every day. to be more specific they're also logfiles generated by certain systems

Comment: @Grove, I still don't see what the problem is, you want to exclude files that end with .log and .something (whatever this might be), use find and locate those files. Save them to an array and then do a find of all files, compare the files in the array with the files find locate (when searching for all files)

Comment: you're right, i was missing your point:)  however it seems that i can do something more elegant from within find itself:  
find -L path -type f \\( -name '*.log' \\) -a ! \\( -name '*.zip' -o -name '*something*' \\) -mtime +3. thanks nonetheless

Comment: @Grove, Just make sure the version of find on Solaris supports that can kind of operation.

Comment: 10x for the heads-up, i know compatibility between linux and solaris is the real problem in this equation. despite the trouble i had till now, it seems to be running smooth on both the test environments

Comment: @Grove, Also, you could simply check for the file ending in a shell script also, no need to run `find` twice when I think about it :) But your solution is good! Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

experimenting around i discovered one can benefit from multiple complex expressions grouped with logical operators like this:

```
find -L path -type f \( -name '*.log' \) -a ! \( -name '*.zip' -o -name '*something*' \) -mtime +3
```

cheers,
G

Comment: Since this solves the problem, you should mark it as accepted (it's OK to accept your own answers).

Comment: yes i know, but i have to wait 2 days before i can do that ;-)

Answer (score 3):

or you could do this:

```
find /appl/ftp -type f -mtime +30 |grep -vf [exclude_file] | xargs rm -rf;
```

Comment: find /appl/ftp -type f -mtime +30 |grep -v [exclude_file] | xargs rm -rf; no need to add "f "with grep

Answer (score 2):

I needed to find a way to provide a hard coded list of exclude files to not remove, but remove everything else that was older than 30 days. Here is a little script to perform a remove of all files older that 30 days, except files that are listed in the [exclude_file].

```
EXCL_FILES=`/bin/cat [exclude_file]`;
RM_FILE=`/usr/bin/find [path] -type f -mtime +30`;

for I in $RM_FILES;
do
     for J in $EXCL_FILES; 
     do
          grep $J $I;
          if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
               /bin/rm $I;
               if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then echo "PROBLEM: Could not remove $I"; exit 1; fi;
          fi;
     done;
done;
```